# run batch file during Windows Setup from autounattend.xml

Tags: batch-file, windows-installation, deployment, windows-pe, autounattend

I want to run a batch file during the `windowsPE` phase of an unattended Windows setup, and the `autounattend.xml` works fine as long as I launch the batch file from its path like this:

```xml
<RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
  <Description>StartUp script</Description>
  <Path>cmd.exe /k D:\startup.bat<Path>
  <Order>6</Order>
</RunSynchronousCommand>
```

```log
2023-11-21 11:41:53,  Info  IBS Command 5: 0x00000000

2023-11-21 11:41:56,  Info  IBS Successfully executed command 'cmd.exe /k "D:\startup.bat"' (exit code 0x00000000)
2023-11-21 11:41:56,  Info  IBS STATUS: SUCCESS (0x00000000)

2023-11-21 11:41:56,  Info  IBS ==== executing user-specified asynchronous commands ====
2023-11-21 11:41:56,  Info  IBS STATUS: SUCCESS (0x00000001)

2023-11-21 11:41:56,  Info  IBS ==== Applying shutdown settings ====
2023-11-21 11:41:56,  Info  IBS No shutdown setting was specified
2023-11-21 11:41:56,  Info  IBS STATUS: SUCCESS (0x00000001)

2023-11-21 11:41:56,  Info  IBS Successfully applied WinPE bootstrap unattend settings
```

**The drive letter can be different, and setup fails when it doesn't find `D:\startup.bat`**

- To search for the file, I found this [script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-identify-drive-letters), and it works fine when I run it from a terminal, but fails when it's run from the answer file:

  ```xml
    <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
      <Description>StartUp script</Description>
      <Path>cmd.exe /k "(FOR %i IN (C D E F G H I J K L N M) DO IF EXIST %i:\startup.bat start %i:\startup.bat)"</Path>
      <Order>6</Order>
    </RunSynchronousCommand>
  </RunSynchronous>
  ```

**I have tried dozens of variations:** 
 using quotes, with/out parenthesis, `echo` instead of `start`, `cmd` without `.exe`, `/c` or `/k`, using `&&`, and creating a variable with `SET` and calling it via `%var%`

- Setup always fails due to an error within the `windowsPE` Pass 1 of the answer file, and I can't figure out why:

  ```log
  2023-11-21 11:25:21,  Info  IBS Command 5: 0x00000000

  2023-11-21 11:27:22,  Info  IBS Successfully executed command 'cmd.exe /k "FOR %i IN (C D E F G H I J K L N M) DO IF EXIST %i:\startup.bat start %i:\startup.bat"' (exit code 0xc000013a)
  2023-11-21 11:27:22,  Info  IBS STATUS: FAILURE (0xc000013a)

  2023-11-21 11:27:22,  Info  IBS ==== executing user-specified asynchronous commands ====
  2023-11-21 11:27:22,  Info  IBS STATUS: SUCCESS (0x00000001)

  2023-11-21 11:27:22,  Info  IBS ==== Applying shutdown settings ====
  2023-11-21 11:27:22,  Info  IBS No shutdown setting was specified
  2023-11-21 11:27:22,  Info  IBS STATUS: SUCCESS (0x00000001)

  2023-11-21 11:27:22,  Error [0x0604a8] IBS Failed applying WinPE bootstrap unattend settings with status 0xc000013a

  2023-11-21 11:27:22,  Info  [0x0640ae] IBSLIB PublishMessage: Publishing message [The Windows PE bootstrap setting specified in the automatic response file could not be applied.]
  ```

Comment: You’ll have to translate the messages into English for us

Comment: have you verified your answer file is correct via [Windows SIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/wsim/windows-system-image-manager-technical-reference) _(apart of the ADK)_? Answer files aren't meant to be modified freehand because it's too easy to create an issue - without verification from SIM the correct component [`RunSynchronous`] was added at the correct step of Pass 1, it would be a guess at best. Generally, when choosing to use a custom answer file, scripts needed would be saved within the `boot.wim` by mounting it and committing the changes.

Comment: Yes, i use SIM to edit, but that's really not my issue here. The answer file has always worked and still works when I use the full path of the batch file.
I was more hoping to get someone to look at the actual script to understand if I am using a wrong syntax

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it by putting the batch file inside the WindowsPE image that launches windows setup (boot.wim). That way the file is always in the X:\ drive and I can just launch it from the answer file with `"cmd.exe /k X:\Windows\Setup\startup.bat"`